# SASS For Loop including 0

Tags: loops, sass

I have a for loop in SASS which loops through page classes to insert a colour break for each module. For example:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 { // the loop
    .m0#{$i} .module-title{
    background-color: nth($m_col_lvl_01_list, $i);
    }
//- end loop
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.m01 .module-title{
    background-color: green;
}
.m02 .module-title{
    background-color: blue;
}
.m03 .module-title{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.m04 .module-title{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

In the task I have at the moment it includes .m00 Is there a way of including 00 in the loop?

Comment: Change `for $i from 1 through 4` to `for $i from 0 through 4`? Am I missing something?

Comment: `from 0 through 4`?

Comment: Hi @JonUleis Its the nth used in the colour sass that is breaking the 0 Error: List index 0 must be a non-zero integer for `nth' background-color: nth($m_col_lvl_01_list, $i); Damn did not notice that.

Comment: SO I think I'll have to live with the 1 0f X loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I found a good explanation in Stack Exchange why ntn does not start at 0 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314537/why-does-nth-child-in-css-start-from-1-instead-of-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can still achieve what you want using 0 in the for loop.

```
$list: (green, blue, orange, red, yellow);

//loop from 0 to the length of the list which isn't hardcoded
@for $i from 0 to length($list) {
    .m0#{$i} .module-title {
        //simply add one to the loop index to get the correct list item
        background-color: nth($list, $i + 1);
    }
}
```

This compiles to the following CSS

```
.m00 .module-title {
  background-color: green;
}

.m01 .module-title {
  background-color: blue;
}

.m02 .module-title {
  background-color: orange;
}

.m03 .module-title {
  background-color: red;
}

.m04 .module-title {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: That is a very interesting solution. Thanks @Black_Enigma

Comment: You're welcome @LaurenceL. I actually left a `debug` statement in there which isn't needed. Just edited the code. Happy to help